# read_double is not equal to print_double

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I simply wanna print the double number I digit but  for example if I digit 2,1 it returns 2. 
MY CODE:

```
li $v0, 7       # select read_double    
syscall         # run read_double
jal p4          # run println

mov.d $f12,$f0
li $v0, 3       # select print_double
syscall         # run print_double
jal p4          # run println
jr $ra
```

anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a decimal *point* (`.`), not a decimal *comma* (`,`).

Comment: Works just fine for me with a decimal point in both QtSpim and PCSpim.

Comment: what version of QtSpim do you have?

Comment: 9.1.12 for Windows. Of course, I removed the `jal p4` instructions, because I've no idea what `p4` is supposed to do.

Comment: it's inexplicable

Answer (score 0):

I was using version 9.1.17 for linux and it didn't work, I downloaded version 9.1.17 for windows and now it works. I spent 2 days for nothing...